# Remove array list values using java(android) sample program

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I wrote a sample script to split the number list added in one by one into a local SQLite db.

**The code**

```
Dbhelper mdbheloper;
String numberlist = "1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234";
int splitNumber = 3;
ArrayList<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(numberlist.split(",")));

if (splitList.size() % splitNumber != 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication,"Number of elelemnts not divisable by split number",1000).show();
} else {
    Arraylist add_value = new Arraylist;

    for (int i = 0; i < splitList.size(); i += splitNumber) {
        System.out.print(((i / splitNumber) + 1) + " group of " + splitNumber +": ");

        for (int j = 0; j < splitNumber; j++) {
            System.out.print(splitList.get(i + j) +", ");
            add_value.add(splitlist.get(i+j);
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Added local db Sqlite
        mdbheloper.insert_value(""+add_value);

        add_value.remove(splitlist.get(i+j)) // error on this line
    }
}
```

**The output**

```
1 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234, 
2 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234, 
3 group of 3: 1234, 1234, 1234,
```

but the issue is first group value will save on local db and another group value could  not been save on one by one its save on overall numberlist values

How to overcome this programs? how will you remove the arraylist  First added 1 group one value then

remove 1 group of 3: 1234,1234,1234 then

added 2 group of 3:1234,1234,1234  then removed  its like cycle process to added local storage  local db given me solution.

row id    number group

1        [1234,1234,1234]

2        [1234,1234,1234]

3         [1234,1234,1234]

to store on local database.

the problems is:

row id      number group

1        [1234,1234,1234]

2        [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]

3         [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]

to store on local database.

Comment: Please, clarify the last part of your question, I couldn't understand what you meant to say.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Beware that you are missing a `;` at the end of the line you've pointed as cause of the error.

Comment: Do you want to add each element of "1 Group of 3" in database and then delete that arraylist so that similar operations can be performed for "2 Group of 3" and "3 group of 3" ?

Comment: yeah i want each element will be store db.  one by one to

Comment: For the same reason you are using "splitNumber " or do you have some other logic associated to it as well? Because if not then you can use single arraylist.

Comment: i will split number in Single array list  to split and added local db, if not possible to added one by one ... i am using  for some logic to insert db.

Comment: I am not getting your point? What is your issue? You are not able to insert elements in database using arraylist?

Comment: my issue is i am insert 1 group values are inserted [1234,1234,1234], 2 group of values also inserted the problem all array list values store [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234] so this purpose i will ask the question to remove the arraylist values.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understood your question completely but so as to remove elements from arraylist you can use arraylist.remove(int index).

Comment: yeah i am using arraylist.remove(int index) , some other methods are  you will using

Comment: Da Small boy obj.clear(); .... its working